# Compatible versions of Gradle, Sonar, clover plugin?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradle-plugin, sonarqube-scan, clover

I am using sonarqube-gradle-plugin v2.2 to generate reports using code coverage data from clover. On my local system, I can see the reports on the sonarqube version 6. But as soon as I run the same gradle task on the build system I start seeing bunch of errors. The build system has sonarqube 5.4. Hence I was wondering which versions are compatible together. Some more information:

- grade version = 3.1
- for generating clover reports, I am using this plugin: com.bmuschko:cradle-clover-plugin:2.0.1

Examples of errors:

- 358 files in clover report did not match any file in SonarQube Index ...
- Use the new property "sonar.web.file.suffixes" instead of the deprecated "sonar.web.fileExtensions"
- [13:37:01]Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
   [13:37:02]Class not found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, I was using ${project.name} instead of ${name} hence it was showing up with a different name.